# Path in .bash_profile is not recognized

Tags: macos

I have the following in .bash_profile:

```
export PATH="/Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/:${PATH}"
```

I even tried it without the string:

```
export PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/:$PATH
```

I know for sure an executable lives in that bin directory:

```
$ cd /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin
$ ./psql
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user
```

However, when I add the path to .bash_profile and then source .bash_profile (and even restart terminal), I get the following:

```
$ psql
-bash: psql: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How about this: `export PATH="/Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/":$PATH` ? And then `source ~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek the `export`s in the question seem to be ok.

Comment: I installed postgresql from here http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#osx  All I am trying to do is get psql and other commands recognized from command line.

Comment: I guess the problem was the order of the export. Adding to the end of the file was only time it worked.

Comment: Your path statement is actually concatenating a path to the original path.  This means your path statement must be on a line _after_ the original path statement, thus why it worked as the last line of the file.

Answer (score 1):

To add /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin to the path simply add the line:

```
export PATH="/Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin:$PATH"
```

to the file ~/.bash_profile. If you have a second similar line starting with `export PATH...` try to concatenate them.

After adding then line quit and open Terminal.app or enter `source ~/.bash_profile` to reload the modified .bash_profile.

Check the path with `echo $PATH` (which should yield: `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin` and the "existence" of psql with `which psql`: `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/psql`.

Afterwards enter `psql -d database_name -U database_user_name` with the following result:

```
Password for user database_user_name: 
psql (9.5.1)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

Simply entering `psql` is as futile as entering `mkdir` or `ssh` only.